# How can I re-create Microsoft Cluster Service resource groups on a different cluster?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-cluster

I use Microsoft Cluster Service on a cluster of Windows Server 2003 machines containing several dozen resource groups. In the process of migrating to newer hardware, I would like move resources to the new machines on resource group at a time spread out over a few days to ease the migration and minimize risk. I was wondering of there was a smarter way to do this than manually re-creating resources on the new and then deleting them on the old cluster? The cluster has already been set up properly, the only missing is the resource groups and the resources they contain (IP, network names, services...).

I have looked through the options of the cluster admin GUI and cluster.exe's commandline options, but haven't found anything like an import/export feature to copy over the configuration of a resource or entire resource group. Does something like this exist?

Comment: Why not add the new hardware to the existing cluster and migrate resources that way?